# AngularJS route not working

Tags: angularjs

I tried to make the 'getting started' tutorial from Angular JS, but I have a problem when setting the route of a link: the controller of that route does not get called when the user clicks on the link.

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('phonecat', []).
config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/phones', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
            controller: PhoneListCtrl
        }).
        when('/phones/:phoneId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
            controller: PhoneDetailCtrl
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/phones'
        });
    }
]);

function PhoneDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;

    $scope.total = 4;
    $http.get('phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.phone = data;
    });
}

function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}
```

Comment: add quotes around your controllers names when setting routes

Comment: +1 Exact same issue. Routes and pages are all set up appropriately, clicking the link updates the URL in the browser, but no page are actually loaded.

Comment: @jaime i think quote around controller name are not required, in one of my demo example i have put up the quotes but it was not working and when i removed the code it started workin. thanks.

Comment: @PrerakK you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

What angularjs version did you use? I follow the tutorial too, and it use angular-1.0.0rc7.js and if I look up in the app.js file, it use `template` rather than `templateUrl`:

```
$routeProvider.when('/phones', {
    template: 'partials/phone-list.html',
    controller: PhoneListCtrl
});
```

so by looking your code, you might want to use `angular-1.0.3.js` or prior version above the RC

Answer (score 1):

This should work but you need to be sure the link is inside the DOM element which is the root of your app; ie `(ng-app='my-app')`.
It's hard to tell without seeing the page markup.

Comment: I had a similar problem and adding the link worked.   But if I go directly to the path or hit the refresh button I get a 404.   Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have html5mode enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by the asker:

> I fixed the problem - actually I had the HTML of the next step of this tutorial and it was messing up with the app, mainly because it had binding with attribute that did not exist in the model yet.

Comment: Asker added solution as edit to the question; I moved it here.